# Toolbar Overlapping Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My layout is being overlapped by the Toolbar. I have to include a 56dp padding to push it down below the toolbar, which makes it awkward to work with (and likely also means I can't use AlignParentTop). The fragment screen (activity_login.xml) is pretty much straight up stock Google-provided code.

[image]

**(Without Padding)**

[image]
**activity_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.myProject.LoginActivity"
android:id="@+id/login2LinearLayout"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <include layout="@layout/login" />
    <include layout="@layout/activity_login" />
    <include layout="@layout/home" />
    <include layout="@layout/my_stats" />
    <include layout="@layout/settings" />
    <include layout="@layout/winners" />
    <include layout="@layout/about" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: show your tool bar xml code (Your activity code)

Comment: I added app_bar_main.xml (I think it's the right one). The tool bar is also just stock google starter code from selecting the Navigation Drawer Activity from the Gallery when you fire up a new project.

Comment: @FiringBlanks: did you find the solution to it?

Comment: No, I tried the response below (by Hetal); encasing it all in a LinearLayout but to no avail.

Answer (score 14):

Put appbar code and main content code in LinearLayout with vertical orientation. That solved problem for me.
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Which XML file did you add the LinearLayout to? I tried it on app_bar_main.xml and it made no difference.

Comment: Did you move the `include` statements somewhere else?

Comment: put include statement inside linear layout

Comment: @giulio happy to help u

Comment: In Google Reference i found note: "This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html . So, i don't think, that this is right solution. Better solution i found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986588/layout-for-fragment-overlapping-toolbar

Comment: @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" not exists

Answer (score 3):

This is very straight forward and easy. Just follow what I tried to say below.

You replace any View by using:

**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.blankFragment, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
```

** 
//Here, blackFragment is id of FrameLayout View. You replace FrameLayout View with Fragment's Layout. Note: It should be FrameLayout or FrameLayout's derivatives Layout.

My whole code is:

1) SettingsActivity.java

**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        mToolbar.setTitle("Settings");
////        remove the left margin from the logo
        mToolbar.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);//for tab otherwise give space in tab
        mToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        // Display the fragment as the main content
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.blankFragment, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**

2) activity_fragment.xml

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!--scroll|snap-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/statusbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**
You can see my Screen after I replaced FrameLayout's View with Fragment's View

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the most simple solution in this situation is just add below line to linear_layout inside of activity_login.xml

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using this

```
int horizontalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int verticalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) + 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getListView().getParent().getParent();
getListView().setPadding(horizontalMargin, topMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);
```

and then you use setupActionBar method to inflate the toolbar